# "Recipe termined with error" when I try to build a LaTeX file in VSCODE

Tags: latex, runtime-error, vscode-extensions, recipe

I've been trying to format text in LaTeX using VsCode for a few days, I've performed these steps:

- Install the LaTeX Workshop extension
- Install MiKTeX
- Install Perl

When testing, an error stating
"Recipe terminated with error. Retry building the project." appeared in yellow, and another "Recipe terminated with error." error appeared in red with the option to open the log. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XDWx.png)

When I try to open the PDF view, an error message stating "Cannot view file PDF file. File not found: file:///c%3A/Users/Pacheco/OneDrive/Documentos/LaTeX/main.pdf" also appears. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF1Jz.png)

This is what is in the log:

```
[17:25:24.564][Commander] BUILD command invoked.
[17:25:24.564][Commander] The document of the active editor: file:///c:/Users/Pacheco/OneDrive/Documentos/LaTeX/main.tex
[17:25:24.565][Commander] The languageId of the document: latex
[17:25:24.565][Manager] Current workspace folders: ["file:///c:/Users/Pacheco/OneDrive/Documentos/LaTeX"]
[17:25:24.566][Manager] Found root file from active editor: %WS1%\main.tex
[17:25:24.566][Manager] Keep using the same root file: %WS1%\main.tex
[17:25:24.567][Event] ROOT_FILE_SEARCHED
[17:25:24.567][Event] STRUCTURE_UPDATED
[17:25:24.568][Commander] Building root file: %WS1%\main.tex
[17:25:24.568][Builder] Build root file %WS1%\main.tex
[17:25:24.569][Builder] outDir: c:/Users/Pacheco/OneDrive/Documentos/LaTeX .
[17:25:24.570][Builder] Preparing to run recipe: latexmk.
[17:25:24.571][Builder] Prepared 1 tools.
[17:25:24.571][Builder] Recipe step 1 The command is latexmk:["-shell-escape","-synctex=1","-interaction=nonstopmode","-file-line-error","-pdf","-outdir=c:/Users/Pacheco/OneDrive/Documentos/LaTeX","c:/Users/Pacheco/OneDrive/Documentos/LaTeX/main"].
[17:25:24.571][Builder] env: {}
[17:25:24.572][Builder] root: %WS1%\main.tex
[17:25:24.572][Builder] cwd: %WS1%
[17:25:24.586][Builder] LaTeX build process spawned with PID 16344.
[17:25:24.638][Builder] Recipe returns with error code 3221225781/null on PID 16344.
[17:25:24.639][Builder] Does the executable exist? $PATH: undefined, $Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Users\Pacheco\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2\bin;;C:\Users\Pacheco\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Pacheco\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\, $SHELL: undefined
[17:25:24.639][Builder] 
[17:25:24.639][Builder] Cleaning auxiliary files and retrying build after toolchain error.
[17:25:24.640][Cleaner] Clean temporary files command The command is latexmk:["-c","c:\\Users\\Pacheco\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\LaTeX\\main.tex"].
[17:25:24.691][Cleaner] The clean command failed. Context: 3221225781.
[17:25:24.692][Event] AUTO_CLEANED
[17:25:24.692][Builder] Recipe step 1 The command is latexmk:["-shell-escape","-synctex=1","-interaction=nonstopmode","-file-line-error","-pdf","-outdir=c:/Users/Pacheco/OneDrive/Documentos/LaTeX","c:/Users/Pacheco/OneDrive/Documentos/LaTeX/main"].
[17:25:24.692][Builder] env: {}
[17:25:24.693][Builder] root: %WS1%\main.tex
[17:25:24.693][Builder] cwd: %WS1%
[17:25:24.711][Builder] LaTeX build process spawned with PID 6740.
[17:25:24.753][Builder] Recipe returns with error code 3221225781/null on PID 6740.
[17:25:24.753][Builder] Does the executable exist? $PATH: undefined, $Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Users\Pacheco\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2\bin;;C:\Users\Pacheco\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Pacheco\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\, $SHELL: undefined
[17:25:24.753][Builder]
```

I have attempted several solutions that are proposed for similar problems and so far none of them worked, solutions such as:

- Create a PATH in the system variable
- Add a line of code `"-shell-escape", //` in `settings.json`
- Change all the code inside `settings.json`

None of these solutions have worked, and the error remains the same. I don't really understand these things, so I'm pretty lost as to what to do.